# Can't push a new docker image to bluemix

Tags: image, docker, push, ibm-cloud

I've created my first node/express app, built a Docker image and deployed a local Docker container for it (with the help of VirtualBox since I am on Windows).  I followed the instructions here:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/images/add-your-own/?org=5918bf71-3a29-446d-b4f7-b4a103341b45&space=929fcbd9-847c-471b-9868-353ad22b8a46&context=containerImages

Was able to get everything to work and pushed to bluemix.  Now, a few weeks later, I am ready to update my container on bluemix.  I have rebuilt my local Docker image and deployed a new local container and everything works fine.  Now I want to replace the image I previously pushed to bluemix.

I do **cf login** followed by **cf ic login** and both work as expected.  I then tag the image as "latest":

```
docker -H tcp://192.168.0.16:2375 tag -f mockchain registry.ng.bluemix.net/gormanm/mockchain:latest
```

And that works fine.  Now I am ready to do the push and issue this command:

```
docker -H tcp://192.168.0.16:2375 push registry.ng.bluemix.net/gormanm/mockchain:latest
```

When I do, instead of pushing the image, it prompts me to login:

```
The push refers to a repository [registry.ng.bluemix.net/gormanm/mockchain] (length: 1)
Sending image list

Please login prior to push:
Username:
```

From everything I have read, it should not be prompting me at this point because I've already done a **cf login** and **cf ic login**.  Furthermore, the prompts it gives me are for Username, Password, and Email Address.  Nevertheless, I enter that info but it always says invalid username/password.

Is bluemix having trouble or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you see the same error if you try `cf ic push registry.ng.bluemix.net/gormanm/mockchain:latest`?

Comment: I get FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Can you please make sure you have the latest cli available? Run 'cf ic update' and it will tell you if an update is available.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be part of the problem:  (1) my cf client was not matching the version on bluemix (and cf ic update is the first step to updating my client) and (2) when I did cf ic login, it was unable to talk to my local Docker daemon because I did not have DOCKER_HOST set to tcp://192.168.0.16:2375 (which is where my local Docker daemon was running).  Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that seems to be part of the problem:

1. My cf client was not matching the version on bluemix (and **cf ic update** is the first step to updating my client)
2. When I did **cf ic login**, it was unable to talk to my local Docker daemon because I did not have DOCKER_HOST set to tcp://192.168.0.16:2375 (which is where my local Docker daemon was running).

Problem solved.